# Reusing disk partition during ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm, preseed

is there a way to tell partman to re-use current disk layout/lvm layout when using preseeding? either that or bypass partman completely?
i'm using a custom preseed file with my own partman recipe. but i cannot find a way to tell partman to re-use an existing lvm configuration and just format the logical volumes.

Comment: maybe attach the relevant bits of your preseed file?

Comment: I am currently looking into http://serverfault.com/questions/587172/reusing-existing-raids-on-preseeded-instalation and https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/PartMan/AutoRaid